# Google Script (JS) Regex - add additional String in matching places

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to replace a piece of String like:

> 1.Manager 22yo with option C. 2.Employee 455eur (...) 3.Product

with

> 1. Manager 22yo with option C.
> 2. Employee 455eur
> 3. Product

I tried doing that:

```
function enterNewLineForAnswers(){


 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
      .getBody();

body.replaceText("[0-9]{1,2}[/.]{1}","\n" + '$&')
}
```

but it gives me escaped '$&' chars instead of the number found by regex. Can you help me find another approach? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `return body.replaceText("[0-9]{1,2}[/.]","\n$&")`

Comment: Unfortunately not, it still returns "$&" as escaped characters

Comment: Not sure if this is supported, but `return body.replace("[0-9]{1,2}[/.]","\n$&")`

Comment: You can't use backreferences in the `.replaceText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script and situation, I think that `body.replaceText("[0-9]{1,2}[/.]{1}","\n" + '$&')` cannot be used. This has already been discussed in the comment. So, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function enterNewLineForAnswers() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var search = "([0-9]{1,2}[/.]{1})";
  var s = body.findText(search);
  var values = [];
  while (s) {
    var text = s.getElement().asText();
    var r = new RegExp(search, "g");
    var k = `{{sample${values.length}}}`;
    values.push([k, text.getText().replace(r, "\n$1")]);
    text.setText(k);
    s = body.findText(search, s);
  }
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  values.forEach(e => body.replaceText(...e));
}
```

- In this sample script, first, the value like `1.Manager 22yo with option C. 2.Employee 455eur (...) 3.Product` is searched and create the replacing texts using `replace` of Javascript and your regex. And, the texts are replaced. I thought that by this flow, your goal is achieved.

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

##### From:

```
1.Manager 22yo with option C. 2.Employee 455eur (...) 3.Product
```

##### To:

```
1.Manager 22yo with option C. 
2.Employee 455eur (...) 
3.Product
```

#### References:

- [findText(searchPattern, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern,-from)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It works as intented, now I need to learn how and how to re-use that knowledge :)